# How to store unique pushnotifications to sqlite database

Tags: ios, sqlite, push-notification

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification: (NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
NSDictionary *local_dictionary=userInfo;
NSLog(@"\n\n%@",local_dictionary);
NSArray *push_array=[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];
NSLog(@"%@",push_array);
NSString *alert=[push_array valueForKey:@"alert"];
NSLog(@"%@",alert);

if (alert)
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement = NULL;
    const char *databasepath=[dbpath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(databasepath, &sqlite_object)==SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"];
        NSString *resultString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: currentTime];
        NSLog(@"%@",resultString);
        NSString *insertSQL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO NOTIFICATIONSTABLE(MESSAGE,TIME) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\")",alert,resultString];
        NSLog(@"%@",insertSQL);
        const char *insert_stmnt=[insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlite_object, insert_stmnt, -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"POSITIVE");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"NEGATIVE");
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(sqlite_object);
}
}
```

This is what i know, please help me to store each push notifications without duplication. My problem is push notifications getting duplicate. Each time i touch the push notification it will add to DB even if it  is already there.

Comment: r u using primary key in your NOTIFICATIONSTABLE

Comment: say something it is easy to optimize the answer and solve your duplicate insterion

Comment: yah i am using autoincrement primary key

Comment: Got the answer guys ,thanks a lot for your contributions and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets go to straight to sqlite query:

```
"INSERT INTO NOTIFICATIONSTABLE(MESSAGE,TIME) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\")"
```

**Here from query it is clearly visible that you have not use any unique constraint for new record.**

You need to add primary key field for identify each notification uniquely. You can not use `autoincrement` field for that.

**Suggestion:**

When you receive any remote notification. Below delegate method will be called.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

It returns `userInfo` which is a `NSDictionary` variable and it contains details of received notification.

From your code i observed that you received `"aps"` and `"alert"` values from that dictionary. Here you required one more parameter which can uniquely identify notification. It may be a `date`, `timestamp` or `notification id`.

So that in database you can use this value when you insert record. And then new query will be like this

```
"INSERT INTO NOTIFICATIONSTABLE(MESSAGE,TIME, NOTIFICATION_ID) VALUES (\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")"
```

`NOTIFICAION_ID` is used as a unique constraint for all notification in database.

Comment: Actualy the ID is autoincrement,so how can i use it to pass value

Comment: You have to create one more field in database, let say 'NOTIFICATION_ID' and use as a primary key. Don't use ID field for that.

Comment: can i pass auto increment value to NOTIFICATION_ID'

Comment: If `NOTIFICATION_ID` is auto-incremented than you will get each time next incremented value. In that case if the same notification received twice, then it will store in database because your field is auto incremented with +1 value. So you have create `NOTIFICATION_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY` field, this will store unique value. And if you try to insert same value it will reject that record.

Comment: how can i pass the auto incremented value to the filed NOTIFICATION_ID that u said to add as Primary Key

Comment: You don't understand. Don't use auto increment value to identify notification thats what i am saying. You some other value than auto increment. You have to tell the server guys that send one more value to identify notification like `date`, `timestamp` or `id`. And this value you have to save in database.